# Berenis ADF - lining figures spacing

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Using `lualatex`, `fontspec` and the Berenis ADF Pro font from an up-to-date `texlive 2017` install, the *proportional lining figures* feature produces *tabular lining figures* and *vice-versa*.

The issue does not appear with old-style figures.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}[Ligatures=TeX]
\setmainfont{Berenis ADF Pro}

\begin{document}

{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[Numbers={Proportional, OldStyle}]
Proportional oldstyle figures : 115, 456
}
and
{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[Numbers={Tabular, OldStyle}]
tabular oldstyle figures : 115, 456.
}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[Numbers={Proportional, Lining}]
Proportional lining figures : 115, 456
}
and
{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[Numbers={Tabular, Lining}]
tabular lining figures : 115, 456.
}

{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[RawFeature=+pnum;+lnum]
Proportional lining figures : 115, 456
}
and
{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[RawFeature=+tnum;+lnum]
tabular lining figures : 115, 456.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sounds like a bug.  should be reported to creator -- the address is in the readme file of the package.

Comment: Yes, the font seems buggy. This won’t solve the problem, but you should avoid those repeated calls to `\fontspec{...}` and use `\addfontfeatures{...}` instead. E.g., your `{\fontspec{Berenis ADF Pro}[Numbers={Proportional, OldStyle}] Proportional oldstyle figures : 115, 456}` should become `{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}Proportional oldstyle figures: 115, 456}`.

Comment: Before you report to the font designer, you should check whether the package provides the current version of the fonts. If not, you should see if you can reproduce with the current version. If so, report to the font designer. If not, report to the LaTeX-package maintainer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Depends whether the package provides the current version of the fonts and, if not, whether the bug is fixed in the current version.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for the advice. I normally use the `\newfontfamily` command to define font macros but for the tests here, I prefered the font-switch to be clear. I haven’t really tested the `\addfontfeatures` command, I’ll think about how I can use it, though.

Comment: @cfr I just confirmed the issue with the original files from the [ADF website](http://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/adffonts.html). As I use `lualatex`, I haven’t tried the package you maintain ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton glad to see I’m not the only one with that problem. Maybe this is simple to solve with `Font Forge` but I don’t know how to use that software. I’ll report this to the font creator soon. Thanks.

Comment: @gwenj It doesn't matter whether you load the package. If you are using the fonts from the package, then it matters whether they are current or not. However, if you can reproduce with current downloads, then it is a font problem and should be reported to the creator, as you say.